# I get the error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to get data from my SQLite database in the assets folder but I get the error `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Product (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM product`.
I did the correct database copy and check the database is exists and also database opens but every time shows that error.
I also added permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml.

How can I solve this?

[image]

DatabaseSql.java

```
public class DatabaseSql extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "sample.sqlite";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.flag.flags/databases/";
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DatabaseSql(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if(mDatabase!=null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public List<TL_Model> getListProduct() {
        TL_Model product = null;
        List<TL_Model> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Product", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            product = new TL_Model(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getString(3));
            productList.add(product);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return productList;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class TouchLearnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imgBackToMain;
    RecyclerView recyclerView_tl;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    List<TL_Model> info_list;
    TL_Model model;
    private DatabaseSql mDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch_learn);
        initViews();
        doClicks();

    }

    private void doClicks() {
        imgBackToMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(TouchLearnActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_toleft,R.anim.slide_outright);
            }
        });


    }

    private void initViews() {
        mDatabase = new DatabaseSql(this);
        checkdbisexists();
        imgBackToMain = findViewById(R.id.imgbacktomaintl);
        recyclerView_tl = findViewById(R.id.recyclertl);
        recyclerView_tl.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        info_list = mDatabase.getListProduct();
        GetDataOfTL adapter = new GetDataOfTL(this,info_list);
        recyclerView_tl.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void checkdbisexists() {
        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseSql.DBNAME);
        if(false == database.exists()){
            mDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
                Log.i("result","Database exists");
            if(CopyDb(this)){
                Log.i("result","copy database successfuly");
            }else{
                Log.i("result","copy database failed");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean CopyDb(Context context){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseSql.DBNAME);
            String outfilename = DatabaseSql.DBLOCATION + DatabaseSql.DBNAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int lenght = 0;
            while ((lenght = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0){
                outputStream.write(buff,0,lenght);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.d("result","DB copied");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("result","DB copy failed" + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_toright,R.anim.slide_outleft);
    }
}
```

Comment: re-install your app

Comment: @JohnJoe I've done several times

Comment: **1)** return to the SQLite Tool, save the database again. Close the tool and re-copy the file into the assets folder. **2)** check the file size in the asset folder (it should be at least 8K, if smaller then for some reason the database is empty (basically at least 4k per table so 4k for sqlite_master and 4k for for the Product table)). **3)** Uninstall App (or delete the App's data) and rerun the App. **That should eliminate any chance of the problem being with the asset file itself.**

Comment: If the above doesn't change matters the change `public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.flag.flags/databases/";` to be **`public static String DBLOCATION = "";`** (change, using refactor, case as it's no longer constant **if you wish**). After line `this.mContext = context;` add line DBLOCATION = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath(); The change line `String outfilename = DatabaseSql.DBLOCATION + DatabaseSql.DBNAME;` to **`String outfilename = DatabaseSql.DBLOCATION;`**. Uninstall or delete the App's data and rerun.

Comment: *I also added permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml.** not necessary but won't hurt.

Comment: @MikeT I did, but did not get any results . can u connect to my pc ??

Answer (score 0):

Normally that happens if you are reading from an empty database. probably you are saving database in a location and reading from another location ( other location has empty data base)